# Centering in <div> Using AlloyUI

Tags: css, html, center

I'm having some trouble getting a few buttons and images to center in a div. Please see the below image:

[image]

Now as you can see, the buttons and images etc are not getting centered (might be worth mentioning that these things are inside a form tag). Then ofcourse I have some test text that does get centered..

My HTML has the following structure:

```
<div class="navigationButtons">
   <form>
   </form>

   <p>Some tect that gets centered...</p>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.navigationButtons{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Isn't the form floating left?

Comment: Provide the relevant HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to test it on your code but this should work.

```
.navigationButtons { 
  width:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

or you could just align the form

```
.navigationButtons form { 
  width:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cory, gave the CSS a try but didn't work unfortunately. I think because this is a portlet that I'm writing for Liferay, Liferay somehow restricts one to use CSS where one normally won't have a problem. Been having alot of issues like this. Otherwise, thanks for the help. Looks like I'm just going to have to hack this thing to work..(hacking makes me feel dirty though, urgh)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. **[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/FkfZU/)**.

Make sure no other CSS rules override the ones you have. Also, please post here **all** of the HTML code as it might be significant.